# Add column to a Dataframe using case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, case-class

I have the dataframe (invoice) which has two columns **firstname** and **lastname** i want to new column **fullname** to be created using case class.The below code doesn't work since the fullname column is not present in the dataframe.

```
**INPUT**

| firstname  | lastname    |
|:-----------|------------:|
| tom        |      jerry  |
| hank       |      polo   |

**OUTPUT**
| firstname  | lastname    | fullname     |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| tom        |      jerry  | tomjerry     |
| hank       |      polo   | hankpolo     |

val names = invoice.as[invoiceColumns].map(updateFields)

case class invoiceColumns (firstname :String,lastname:String,fullname:String)

  def updateFields(c: invoiceColumns): invoiceColumns= {
    val fullname = c.first+c.last+c.fullname
    c.copy(fullname = fullname)
  }
```

Comment: You can use withColumn("fullname",concat($"first",$"last")) function

Comment: ya ,but i have lots of columns in my dataframe which has more function like this so it would be too clumsy to use too many withcolumns, so i thought to use case class

Comment: Ok, can you post your invoice dataframe sample data and your expected output ??

Comment: how do i create a table here

Comment: use ``` around your code.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of different approaches.

### Using case classes for both input and output

If you can define a case classes for both input and output, this can be done safely using the Dataset API:

```
case class Input(firstname: String, lastname: String)
case class Output(firstname: String, lastname: String, fullname: String)
object Output {
  def apply(in: Input): Output =
    Output(in.firstname, in.lastname, in.firstname + in.lastname)
}

Seq(Input("tom", "jerry"), Input("hank", "polo"))
  .toDS()
  .map(Output.apply)
  .show()
```

```
+---------+--------+--------+
|firstname|lastname|fullname|
+---------+--------+--------+
|      tom|   jerry|tomjerry|
|     hank|    polo|hankpolo|
+---------+--------+--------+
```

### Using a case class only for the output

This is less safe as the column names are checked runtime:

```
case class Output(firstname: String, lastname: String, fullname: String)
object Output {
  def apply(firstname: String, lastname: String): Output =
    Output(firstname, lastname, firstname + lastname)
}

Seq(("tom", "jerry"), ("hank", "polo"))
  .toDF("firstname", "lastname")
  .map(row =>
    Output(row.getAs[String]("firstname"), row.getAs[String]("lastname")))
  .show()
```

yields the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is useful -

### Alternative-1

```scala
case class invoiceColumns (firstname :String,lastname:String,fullname:String)

val df3 = Seq(("tom", "jerry"), ("hank", "polo")).toDF("firstname", "lastname")
    df3.show(false)
    df3.printSchema()
    /**
      * +---------+--------+
      * |firstname|lastname|
      * +---------+--------+
      * |tom      |jerry   |
      * |hank     |polo    |
      * +---------+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
      */

    val p = df3.withColumn("fullname", concat(col("firstname"), col("lastname")))
      .as[invoiceColumns]
    p.show(false)
    p.printSchema()
    /**
      * +---------+--------+--------+
      * |firstname|lastname|fullname|
      * +---------+--------+--------+
      * |tom      |jerry   |tomjerry|
      * |hank     |polo    |hankpolo|
      * +---------+--------+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- fullname: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### Alternative-2

```scala
case class invoiceColumns2 (firstname :String,lastname:String,fullname:String) {
  def this(firstname :String,lastname:String) = {
    this(firstname, lastname, firstname + lastname)
  }
}


val p1 = df3.map{case Row(firstname: String, lastname: String) => new invoiceColumns2(firstname, lastname)}
    p1.show(false)
    p1.printSchema()
    /**
      * +---------+--------+--------+
      * |firstname|lastname|fullname|
      * +---------+--------+--------+
      * |tom      |jerry   |tomjerry|
      * |hank     |polo    |hankpolo|
      * +---------+--------+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- fullname: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

Comment: @minnu, is this solution helping you?